# Avoid stepping in Lava Circles

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection

I am trying to figure out how to write an AI avoidance algorithm for a game to not step on lava areas.  The safe distance from the center of the lava object is a static 25 range. 
 If it was just 1 lava object I would calculate the distance between Player and the Object, then calculate the angle and move backwards x range until its 25 range away.

But because there can be more than 1 lava object each with its 25 range safe radius.  All 3 need to be taken into consideration otherwise it might move away from 1 and step onto another.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: 1]

Comment: do you have an upper-bound on the lava objects

Comment: yes. they are all the exact same size?

Comment: Do you want to compute a path (say a minimal length path) to a destination point, avoiding going within distance 25 of any lava centroid?  Or do you just want to compute a path (say a minimal length path) that gets you out of all lava circles, assuming you are currently in one?

Comment: what is the desired "output" of the algorithm? is it a yes/no (e.g safe/not safe), minimum distance from unsafe? a direction to move? what size of move? is it a grid or a continuous landscape?

Answer (score 0):

> If it was just 1 lava object I would calculate the distance between Player and the Object, then calculate the angle and move backwards x range until its 25 range away.

That's essentially the right idea, you just have to scale it. Create a vector for each lava circle. The angle should represent "away" from the circle, and the magnitude represents how far away it is. Then you can add these together to represent a steering vector. It's not *perfect*, but you can tweak it to suit your particular needs well.

That's just the bare basics, but the principle can be applied to all kinds of steering, like pursuit, avoidance, wall following, etc.

The best reference I know of to send you to is [Steering Behaviors For Autonomous Characters](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/) by Craig Reynolds(the creator of BOIDS). The site's pretty old, but the information is as good as ever.